# Get all named cache in appfabric

Tags: appfabric-cache

We have a cache server. On that we have created multiple named cache. Over the time we have created multiple named cache.

Is there is any command which will return me all the named cache i have created?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As specified [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff718177%28v=azure.10%29.aspx), you can use the cmdlet `Get-Cache`.